# How to establish a variable to count the number of matching characters?

Tags: python, variables, count

I am brand new to this, I don't know where to start,
**Here is my current code that I am working with:**

```
    original_word: str = input("Enter a 5-character word: ")
    character_one: str = input("Enter a single character: ")
    print("Searching for " + character_one + " in " + original_word)
    if character_one == original_word[0]:
        print(character_one + " found at index 0")
    if character_one == original_word[1]:
        print(character_one + " found at index 1")
    if character_one == original_word[2]:
        print(character_one + " found at index 2")
    if character_one == original_word[3]:
        print(character_one + " found at index 3")
    if character_one == original_word[4]:
        print(character_one + " found at index 4")
```

**Here are my instructions:**
Now that you are finding the indices of the word that match the character being searched for, establish a variable to count the number of matching characters. Before you find any matching characters, what should you initialize this variable to? Each time you find a match, increase your counting variable’s value by 1. Finally, print out a message that indicates how many instances of the character you found in the input word.

You will need to exactly match the output formatting of the examples below. Specifically, notice, there are different messages for when no matches are found, a singular match is found, or multiple matches are found (i.e.: No instances vs. 1 instance vs. 2 instances). You will need to use a nested if-else statement in order to output these messages correctly. Correction: you do not need to use a nested ‘if-else’ statement.
Please do not use the .count() method to get the total number of instances, this will result in a grade reduction.

Comment: DO NOT post code as images.  Instead, cut-and-paste your code into the question.  That way, we can try the code ourselves, without having to retype every line (which none of us will do).

Answer (score 0):

Any time you find yourself repeating code like that, you need to think about a loop instead.

```
counter = 0
for c in original_word:
    if c == character_one:
        counter += 1
print("Found it", counter, "times.")
```

However, there are built-in functions to do this:

```
counter = original_word.count(character_one)
```

Comment: I have typed out the first box of code; however, it is not printing. I am trying not to use the .count line because I was instructed to not use it.

Comment: Well, it can't "not print".  There's a print statement there.  You must have cut and pasted it incorrectly.